# How do I limit generated file name from a VB script?

Tags: vb.net, outlook

I'm working on a project, and need to export existing Notes from Outlook to a text file. I've managed to get a working script together that scrubs disallowed characters from the note, and names the text file with the Subject/first line of the note, but where I am running into an issue is file name length. I need to be able to tell the script to truncate the file name after X number of characters so that the created text file falls under Windows max character limit. I can't figure out how to do it without resorting to a generic name scheme of Note1.txt, Note2.txt, which will not work for the situation that I need the text files for, they need to retain as much of the name as possible for later identification.

This is what I have so far:

```js
Sub NotesToTXT()
    myfolder = "c:\appsnotes\notes\"
    Set sanitize = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
 
    sanitize.IgnoreCase = True
    sanitize.Global = True
 
    Set myNote = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI").PickFolder
    For cnt = 1 To myNote.Items.Count
        sanitize.Pattern = "(((?![a-zA-Z0-9,@,{,},#,&,%,=,+,_,-,^,(,),;,',$,,]).) )+"
        noteName = sanitize.Replace(myNote.Items(cnt).Subject, "_")
        sanitize.Pattern = "\-+"
        noteName = sanitize.Replace(noteName, "-")
        myNote.Items(cnt).SaveAs myfolder & noteName2 & ".txt", OlSaveAsType.olTXT
    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

VBA (nor the Outlook object model) doesn't provide anything for that. The best what you can do is to generate your own short names, for example, based on user names, dates and etc.